# services.AddSignIn() twice I get next error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Cookies'

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

From organizations I want to get through AzureGraph the users and invite those to my application. Users not having AzureB2B or not able to give admin consent must be able to use AzureB2C so that users stay interested in my application.

I am trying to combine the AzureB2C and AzureB2B like in the WoodGrove sample (which is outdated for Core 3.1). I struggle with all the `services.AddSignIn()` through `services.AddAuthentication()`

If I just add `AddSignIn()` twice I get next error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Cookies'

If you add them separately, 2 separate cookies are created and this is not an issue at all. What do I wrong? [I understand that the AzureGraph is not possible with AzureB2C, other thread]

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1
            options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();                
        });

        services.AddOptions();

        //If you want to run this sample using in memory db, uncomment the line below (options.UseInMemoryDatabase) and comment the one that uses options.UseSqlServer.
        //services.AddDbContext<SampleDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MultiTenantOnboarding"));
        services.AddDbContext<SampleDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SampleDbConnStr")));

        services.AddScoped<ITodoItemService, TodoItemService>();

        // Add Microsoft Graph support
        services.AddScoped<IMSGraphService, MSGraphService>();

        services.AddSignIn(options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options);
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
                string tenantId = context.SecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "tid" || x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid")?.Value;

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantId))
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Unable to get tenantId from token.");

                var dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SampleDbContext>();

                var authorizedTenant = await dbContext.AuthorizedTenants.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.TenantId == tenantId);

                if (authorizedTenant == null)
                    throw new UnauthorizedTenantException("This tenant is not authorized");
            };
            options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
            {
                if (context.Exception != null && context.Exception is UnauthorizedTenantException)
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Home/UnauthorizedTenant");
                    context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            };
        }, options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options);
        });

        services.AddSignIn(options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options);
            options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = (context) =>
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/");
                context.HandleResponse();

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            };
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
                string tenantId = context.SecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "tid" || x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid")?.Value;

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantId))
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Unable to get tenantId from token.");

                var dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SampleDbContext>();

                var authorizedTenant = await dbContext.AuthorizedTenants.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.TenantId == tenantId);

                if (authorizedTenant == null)
                    throw new UnauthorizedTenantException("This tenant is not authorized");
            };
            options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
            {
                if (context.Exception != null && context.Exception is UnauthorizedTenantException)
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Home/UnauthorizedTenant");
                    context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            };
        }, options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options);
        });          

        services.AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi(Configuration, new string[] { GraphScope.UserReadAll })
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        services.AddRazorPages();

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve Azure AD B2C user account management with .NET Core and Microsoft Graph..?

Comment: No, B2C does not that option (I get other error for that). I want to have AzureAD and AzureB2C side by side like in Woodgrove. However, with every framework release, things change or shift in libraries. So how to do that in .NETCore 3.1 as tried above.

Comment: Try to develop Azure AD B2C application federating Azure AD B2B identity as  on of the Idp. Using the [Azure ad b2c custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant-custom?tabs=applications) you can achieve preferred requirement.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that. So the custom policy allows me to read multiple tenants, but guest users cannot sign-in. Is it possible to retrieve the full AD users of the tentants? Why do I always see a separate sigin for own Azure AD? For instance on Microsoft sites you see 'Microsoft Employees' next to Azure B2C. Is this to allow own AD or runs this then also through custom policy?

Comment: using custom policies you can provide multiple idp (Azure AD,gmail,facebook,local) which helps the user to login with preferred id. If your request for the consents for the reading the user profile, after user acceptance you will be able to ready the AD users. For entire Tenant users you need Admin consent approval for that.

Comment: regarding  the sign in page based on the choosen idp it request user credentials  for authentication

Comment: Hi @V4A001 does the above comments helps you to resolve your issue or still looking for any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

AddSignIn(...) is by default creating a cookie with an authentication scheme named "Cookies". So when calling AddSignIn for the second time, you should provide a different name to avoid conflict. That can be done using the "cookieScheme" parameter on the AddSignIn.